# What is the specific requirement to use Dagger2 in any android application? What are the actual benefits of using dagger2 in an android application?

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I read the dagger 2 documentation but still not able to find that in what condition I should use dagger2 in my application and what are the benefits of its implementation?

Comment: It's a dependency injection framework. So it's useful whenever you need to use dependency injection. Which is whenever you need to call a method in your code that belongs to another class. Which is pretty much always? I like this article  https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/26/clean-code-in-android-applications just replace Guice with Dagger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beside testing, why do we need Dagger 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895802/beside-testing-why-do-we-need-dagger-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) to use Dagger2, you need to include it as a dependency in your project.

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Then you can use Dagger2.

---

2.) Whenever you have a class which is the dependency of another class.

So if you have something like this:

```
public int getNewRandomNumber() {
    return new Random().nextInt(5000);
}
```

Then you have an implicit dependency on `Random` and it is not mockable.

So you might want to provide this as a dependency to the method instead:

```
public int getNewRandomNumber(Random random) {
   return random.nextInt(5000);
}
```

But you might be using `Random` in a bunch of places, so you might want to provide it to the class itself:

```
public class RandomGenerator {
    private final Random random;

    public RandomGenerator(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }
}
```

After which the question surfaces: if you need an instance of `RandomGenerator`, where are you getting `Random` from?

Surely this is stupid:

```
RandomGenerator gen = new RandomGenerator(new Random());
```

Wouldn't it be nicer to do either this:

```
RandomGenerator randomGenerator = component.randomGenerator();
```

or

```
@Inject
RandomGenerator randomGenerator;
```

---

Well apparently with Dagger it's pretty easy

```
@Module
public class RandomModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Random random() {
        return new Random();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={RandomModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Random random();
    RandomGenerator randomGenerator();
}
```

then

```
@Singleton
public class RandomGenerator {
    private final Random random;

    @Inject
    public RandomGenerator(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }
}
```

or

```
@Singleton
public class RandomGenerator {
    @Inject
    Random random;

    @Inject
    public RandomGenerator() {
    }
}
```

---

You can read more about dependency injection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)